# Trouble understanding the event flow of the Twitter for AS3 library by susisu

Tags: actionscript-3, twitter

I'm new to AS3, really new, and all I'm trying to do is a simple call to the Search API to get 100 tweets with a specific hashtag working with [this library](https://github.com/susisu/Twitter-for-AS3/).
So in my main class I have a twitter object and a function called retrieveTweetsByHashtag(hashtagSt:String). In this function I do:

```
var retrievedInfo:TwitterRequest = myTwitterObject.search_tweets('#'+hashtagSt,null,null,null,null,100);
```

But I'm not really getting how events work, I guess.
After that I traced retrievedInfo.data, retrievedInfo.response .
There I gathered that retrievedInfo.data contains the query elements, and retrievedInfo.response seems to be an empty string (though perhaps it shouldn't be?), so I don't know where to look for the data I'm trying to find.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen for the event that is being dispatched by `TwitterRequest`, in this case it appears to dispatch `TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE` when the request has completed:

```
var retrievedInfo:TwitterRequest = myTwitterObject.search_tweets('#'+hashtagSt,null,null,null,null,100);

// add the event listener
retrievedInfo.addEventListener(TwitterRequestEvent.COMPLETE, onInfoRetrieved);

// handle the event
function onInfoRetrieved(e:TwitterRequestEvent):void
{
    // retrieve the response property from the target of the event (in this case, the target was retrievedInfo 
    var response:String = TwitterRequest(e.target).response;
}
```

Comment: thanks, worked ok. I'd tried something like this, don't know which was my mistake but it's gone now. I think i was using e:Event instead of e:TwitterRequestEvent

Comment: Just for the record: `TwitterRequestEvent` inherits (extends from) `Event`, so that shouldn't have been a problem. `TwitterRequestEvent` doesn't have any special properties, so it's basically the same as a regular `Event`.